# Launch Cryengine Game Engine

Tags: cryengine

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/750532/how-to-install-the-cryengine-sdk
```

I followed the above webpage and successfully able to compile source code of Cryengine, now I am having `linux_x64_clang_profile` folder and i am searching how to start cryengine, where is the editor ?? Engine ?? launcher ??

Can you help me to start Cryengine ?? and i have searched documentation and google and not able to found where to start the editor/engine ??

Please excuse me ,its my first time to use Cryengine over Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Editor is still Windows Only. You would have to prepare the WAF Build and then compile the Engine:

http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC4/Getting+Started+with+WAF

But as I said, this only allows running the Game itself.